# Prestashop updateQuantity php modification

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to make changes below prestashop checkProductStock function, so that FOREACH and every id_product_attribute from id_product, the stock_quantity gets updated. Below codes only update one id_product_attribute from id_product. Any idea?

```
 protected function checkProductStock($product, $id_order_state){
   if ($id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_CANCELED') &&    $id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR')) {
        $update_quantity = true;
        if (!StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['id_product'])) {

            $update_quantity = StockAvailable::updateQuantity($product['id_product'], $product['id_product_attribute'], -(int)$product['cart_quantity']);
        }

        if ($update_quantity) {
            $product['stock_quantity'] -= $product['cart_quantity'];
        }

        if ($product['stock_quantity'] < 0 && Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT')) {
            $this->outOfStock = true;
        }
        Product::updateDefaultAttribute($product['id_product']);
    }
}
```

Comment: that is only called when creating an orderdetail. any particular reason to update the quantity on the other attributes? and change it based on what? if they are in the cart, they will be changed to.